# how to check which member has not complete his pair match mean left and right under him

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, recursive-query

Hello Friend Thank for view my question.
My Question in details

I have a table tree like this

USERID     LEFT   RIGHT

123        852    258
852        456    654 
258        357    753
456               459
654
357
753
459

I have a form like

```
<div class="form-group form-control-default required">
    <label for="exampleInputtext1">Sponsor ID:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sponsorid" id="exampleInputtext1" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>" placeholder="Enter Sponsor Name" readonly>                        
</div>

<div class="form-group form-control-default required">
    <label for="exampleInputtext1">Sponsor Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sname" id="exampleInputtext1" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" placeholder="Enter Sponsor Name" readonly>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-control-default required">
    <label for="exampleInputtext1">Position:</label>
    <select name="postion" style="width: 100%;" data-toggle="select2" data-placeholder="Select a State .." data-allow-clear="true" onchange="getparentid(this.value)"> 
        <option value="left">LEFT</option>
        <option value="right">RIGHT</option>                        
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-control-default">
    <label for="exampleInputtext1">Parent id:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="parentid" id="exampleInputtext1" placeholder="Enter Parent id">
</div>

<div class="form-group form-control-default">
    <label for="exampleInputtext1">Parent Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname" id="exampleInputtext1" placeholder="Enter Parent Name">
</div>
```

Where i want to input sponsor id and select `left` or `right` then `parent id` automatically fill with "which member left and right not complete"

my recursively check function

```
public function fetch_user() {
    $sideoption = $_POST['action'];
    $data['fetch_user_by_side'] = $this - > mymod - > fetch_user_by_side($sideoption);
    if ($sideoption == 'left') {
        $cuser = $data['fetch_user_by_side'][0] - > left;
    } else {
        $cuser = $data['fetch_user_by_side'][0] - > right;
    }
    $val = $this - > recur($cuser);
    echo $val;
    //exit;
    //$leftside = $data['fetch_user_by_side'][]->left;
    //$leftside = $data['fetch_user_by_side'][]->right;
}

function recur($cuser) {
    $data['fetch_user_by_side1'] = $this - > mymod - > fetch_user_by_side1($cuser);
    //print_r($data['fetch_user_by_side1']);
    $leftside = $data['fetch_user_by_side1'][0] - > left;
    $rightside = $data['fetch_user_by_side1'][0] - > right;
    //return $leftside;
    if (empty($leftside) || empty($rightside)) {
        //$this->recur($leftside);
        return $cuser;
    } else {
        //$this->recur($rightside);
        $this - > recur($leftside);
    }
    //return "hi";
}
```

and jquery and Ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getparentid(sideoption){                        
        $.ajax({ url: '<?php echo  base_url(); ?>index.php/mycon/fetch_user',
            data: {action: sideoption},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output) {
                alert(output);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So what is wrong?

Comment: my ajax return null in level 3

Comment: first level return correct and 2nd level also